# Finding time complexity of a program using recurrence relation

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

```
long long foo(long long n) {
    long long i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            i = i + 6;
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 1) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 2) {
            i = i + 16;
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 3) {
            i = i + 11;
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 4) {
            i = i + 21;
        }
   }
}
```

I need to find time complexity of this program

I first found the values of i that would go in this loop which were: 0,6,7,23,34,55,61.... which will remain fixed for any value of n.
Then I found the number of iterations required for each i which was periodic after every 5 values that are: 4,6,8,10,12.
These iterations can be expressed as 2*((i%5)+2) where i is the current value of i in the while loop. Like for 23, the total iterations will be 10. And I think I need to find the sum to find the time complexity but I don't know how to go further after this step.

Comment: Remember that for calculating time complexity, we generally don't care about constants. For example, if for some input n a function takes n + 10000 steps to execute, its time complexity is still O(n). Or if it takes n/1000 steps, it's also O(n). On the other hand, if it takes 5*n^2 steps, then the complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One iteration of the loop will increase `i` with a value between 1 and 21. To establish the time complexity there is no need to dig deeper in when exactly which value is added to `i`.

Naively we could say that in the *worst* case always 1 is added to `i` (even though we could see that if this happens in one iteration, it will not in the next -- but it is not very relevant), so that means there will be at most  iterations. In the best case always 21 is added to `i` (again this wouldn't happen twice in a row -- but it is not relevant), so we would have at least /21 iterations of the loop.

Either way,  and /21 are both O(), so the time complexity is O().

#### Details...

Now, just for the fun of it, we could dive deeper: we see that every possible value that gets added to `i` is a multiple of 5 plus 1. This means that in each iteration, it will be the *next* `if` block that gets executed and after the last one has executed, the first one will be executed in the next iteration, ...etc.

So in 5 iterations of the loop all those values will have been added exactly once: in five iterations  will have increased with 6+1+16+11+21=55.

There are thus 5(/55) +  iterations of the loop (with  < 5). This is a better estimation then we did first, but it doesn't change anything to the time complexity, which was already established to be O().

#### Recurrence Relation

As you mention this, let's also define a recurrence relation, even though the above is more than enough to establish the time complexity:

The only time there are zero iterations is when  is 0:

(0) = 0

As in the first iteration  becomes 6, there will be one iteration for when  is less than 7:

(1..6) = 1

When  is 7, a second iteration gets executed where  increases from 6 to 7:

(7) = 2

The third iteration will increase  from 7 to 23, so:

(8..23) = 3

The fourth iteration will increase  from 23 to 34, so:

(24..34) = 4

And the fifth iteration will increase  from 34 to 55:

(34..55) = 5

When more iterations occur a similar pattern repeats so that now we can add the recursive equation:

() = (−55) + 5, for  > 54